# Isolation of sessions and interface parameters Java EE

Tags: java, jsp, session, extjs, arraylist

we have a JavaEE Web application that runs on Tomcat5 server (jsp, java and extjs are used on development of this tool).

We observe sometimes, particularly when the application is highly used, that some **session variables or interface fields  are mixed up** in **servlets**.

This means that : when one user connects, his parameters are kept in the sessions.

After an **update or insertion** of data in the database ORACLE,the system returns the name of  another user who was probably connected at the same time on a different navigator or a different computer.
Others times the request.getparameter gets a **values** **from different clients or user interfaces**.
Thank you to help me fix this problem.

Comment: I bet your servlets have fields and you change their values in `doGet` and/or `doPost` method.

Comment: All the elements got in the servlet are supposed to be originated from the same user session interface. But sometimes the user id or values are mixed up in the http Protocol that brings data to the servlet.

Comment: That's not what I mean. Please provide an example of your servlet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've finally understood how servlet.java works.
I works like main process that create a thread for any call
thus, all attributes of such class are common to all thread and we are not sure of the result that we get when accessing them.

If we want any client to use those variables in a private context, we must put them in the function "**doGet**" or "**doPost**" as local variables.

My problem have them been solved

Answer (score 0):

The only way for this to happen is if you have a singleton somewhere that keeps track of the session and for some reason this singleton is mixing up the variables between sessions.

You can try this: Instead of differentiating a user only by its credentials (assuming you are not using Federation), return a token, unique amongst all sessions to the user logging in, and make the user send that unique id with every request. This way you will be able to differentiate the request/responses even if the user logs in using many different browsers.

But again, this will only happen when you do something like having a singleton connecting the session, by itself the session would not exchange variables amongst them.

Comment: I've tried to keep the session id in the GUI and compare with the other taken from the request when i reach the servlet. But this does not assure me that every parameters are from the same user

Comment: Hmmmm. I think you are doing too much and not allowing servlets (and filters) to do their job. Try reading more about how they work.

Comment: Please would you sent me an address where i can find those details about servlets .java and how to uses them efficiently and between many web client

Comment: @user3622677 [How do servlets work? Instantiation, session variables and multithreading](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3106452/1065197)